# Symfony2 redirect action shows intermediate page

Tags: php, symfony, redirect

I've been using the following method for redirecting users from a page to another whenever they have successfully achieved something in the lines of a CRUD action;

```
return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('_my_route'));
```

This, normally goes well. The user finishes the action, and gets redirected without any problems to the following page. But now I've got an action that does it differently without no apparent reason. It finished my request in the controller. It hits the above redirect statement and it shows me the following intermediate page;

> Redirecting to /my/route/somewhere/on/the/site/.

And after showing this to me, it actually redirects me to the page I'm looking for after a short pause. Why is this happening? And what can I do to prevent it?
I don't wanna see that I'm being redirected. And what's more frustrating; how is it possible that 19 redirects DONT do this, and this one does?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because the headers have already been sent, somewhere. Check for any debug code - in fact, if you keep hitting `esc` on your keyboard to stop the javascript location change, and then inspect the source, you may be able to see what characters are being sent to the browser before your attempt your `redirect`.

Comment: The weird thing is, I don't do anything else in this action than in any other actions in the same controller. It's all the same logic.. The only thing I can think of is that I use a bundle that uploads files which is set up via my Doctrine Entity annotations. That bundle might intervene when sending the form and the files..